# Fastlane gym export .app

Tags: ios, calabash-ios, fastlane

On the gym description says: *gym builds and packages iOS and macOS apps for you. It takes care of all the heavy lifting and makes it super easy to generate a signed **ipa** or **app** file.* 
I can't search in documentation how to export .app file. I need the .app file and path to start the calabash tests in my jenkins CI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are planning on supporting .ipas in the Calabash iOS tool chain.  Until then, use `ditto` to unzip the .ipa.

```
$ xcrun ditto -xk path/to/Your.ipa ./
$ mv ./Payload/Your.app path/to/somewhere/else
```